# How to evaluate performance of a simulated system

Tags: matlab

1. I have created a database (DB) of amplitde vs time delay of UWB pulses originating from various (known) points in a certain (known) "region" in a space. This DB also stores region name, since there are several regions . This is "training phase".
2. the folowup part is called "localization phase" -- I assume that there is a signal coming from one of the regions ..I don't know which, I changed parameters of simulation and now know this new comer's amplitude vs delay profile. I will cross-correlate this new signal with the ones stored in my DB in #1 above. If any of the signals matches, I can then say that the signal was from region 1 or 2 or 3 .. etc.
3. My problem: How do I evaluate this system? That it fared better or worse? If I had resources, I could probably buy or borrow a network analyzer, antenna, etc, and measure the delay profile and that would give me something to compare against.

Now without that option, what are my (other) options?

Gurus, please advise. 
Thank you.

Comment: To evaluate a system, you need some kind of (preferably quantitative) metric. What are you trying to compare it to? "That it fared better or worse" than what?